# What do you call 14th day of when the Moon appears fully illuminated from the Earth?

Tags: word-request

In my native language, we call it “chaudhanvi” (literal English: 14th day).

> “You are the Sun or the Moon of 14th day (i.e. you’re bloomed like the Moon) or whatever you are. I swear by God you are beyond compare.”

But actually, the Moon appears fully on its 15th day. In my language some poets use ‘14th day of the Moon’ to praise their beloveds as their beloveds are as beautiful and young as no one is.

Answer (score 1):

In English the moon at its brightest and most visible is called a full moon. This happens approximately every 30 days.

Comment: Hmmm! It appears from 1 to 15 days and approximately for 15 days it is hidden.

Comment: Partially hidden. Here is a link to the phases of the moon and the names that are associated with each phase:

https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/moon/phases.html

Comment: @Jay Ho, in your comment above, it sounds like you are referring to the difference between a "waxing moon" (growing larger over approximately 14-15 days) and a "waning moon" (growing smaller for the next 14-15 days). The "full moon" happens once per cycle.

Comment: Would this answer seem more relevant to Jay Ho if you went into more detail to describe the stages of the moon? We are obviously working across cultures here. Thirty days includes the entire cycle, but there is a significant difference between the first and last fourteen days. Might it be relevant to the question to explain this, given the cross-cultural dialogue?